# Yii2 gridview export to pdf with custom template and filtered data

Tags: gridview, yii2, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to export my gridview into pdf with no luck :(. This is a part of my controller code:

```
class LntTripsController extends Controller
{
    protected $repquery; // my only idea is to pass query parameters via global variable
    .................
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new LntTripsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        $this->repquery = Yii::$app->request->queryParams; // save request here
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
.............
//Here I do export with custom template: 

    public function actionReport() {

        $searchModel = new LntTripsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($this->repquery); //restore request here

        $content = $this->render('report', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);

        $pdf = Yii::$app->pdf;
        $mpdf = $pdf->api;
        $mpdf->WriteHtml($content);
        return $pdf->render();
    }
}
```

The function `actionIndex()` works fine, but `actionReport()` always prints out the full table even when it was filtered in `actionIndex()`. Variable `$this->repquery` always `NULL` in `actionReport()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call actionReport the controller is newly created and then you lost the queryParams you saved..

if you want save this params don't save in a controller 
you can store the value in

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
```

see this doc for detail of session management http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html

http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/session-handling-in-yii-framework-2-0/

Comment: but LntTripsSearch is also newly created in actionReport() same data loss hear. maybe there any other way to pass data between actions?

Comment: You can pass data between action but not in this way .. you want store the queryParam and after retrive this value.,. for this you can use the session ..

Comment: How you call the report ?.. if where you call the report you know or can know the queryParam the you can call the report passing this value..

Answer (score 0):

You will not get value using `$this->repquery` because `$this` refer to current object.
You have two methods and both have different objects:

```
$searchModel = new LntTripsSearch();
```

So, what you have to do is just use `$repquery` instead of `$this->repquery`.

```
protected $repquery;

public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new LntTripsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $repquery = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

public function actionReport() 
{
    $searchModel = new LntTripsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($repquery); 

    $content = $this->render('report', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

    $pdf = Yii::$app->pdf;
    $mpdf = $pdf->api;
    $mpdf->WriteHtml($content);
    return $pdf->render();
}
```

Comment: then I will get "Undefined variable: repquery" exception

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. Session is the solution in my case.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new LntTripsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    // check if a session is already open
    if (!$session->isActive){
        $session->open();// open a session
    } 
    // save query here
    $session['repquery'] = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}


public function actionReport() 
{

    $searchModel = new LntTripsSearch();
    // restore query using session
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->session->get('repquery'));

    $content = $this->render('report', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
    // create pdf
    $pdf = Yii::$app->pdf;
    $mpdf = $pdf->api;
    $mpdf->WriteHtml($content);
    return $pdf->render();
}
```

Comment: this is not  fair .. in not right take the suggestion of who help you and use this info for give to  yourself a (stolen )  accept answer ...